# Which fromVersion to use when upgrading from 2.5.1 to 2.5.2

Tags: thingsboard

**Component**

- Installation

**Description**

I tried to upgrade from 2.5.1 to 2.5.2 on Ubuntu using the instructions at
https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/install/upgrade-instructions/#upgrading-to-252

The database used is Cassandra.

The instructions state:

```
# Finally, execute upgrade script and specify your previous ThingsBoard version. 
$ sudo /usr/share/thingsboard/bin/install/upgrade.sh --fromVersion=2.4.3
```

I don't understand why --fromVersion=2.4.3 is used here. The install page says

> NOTE: These upgrade steps are applicable for ThingsBoard version 2.5.1. In order to upgrade to 2.5.2 you need to upgrade to 2.5.1 first.

Since I am upgrading from 2.5.1 I tried `$ sudo /usr/share/thingsboard/bin/install/upgrade.sh --fromVersion=2.5.1` but got this result:

```
 ===================================================
 :: ThingsBoard ::       (v2.5.2)
 ===================================================

Starting ThingsBoard Upgrade from version 2.5.1 ...
Unexpected error during ThingsBoard installation!
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to upgrade ThingsBoard, unsupported fromVersion: 2.5.1
        at org.thingsboard.server.install.ThingsboardInstallService.performInstall(ThingsboardInstallService.java:169)
        at org.thingsboard.server.ThingsboardInstallApplication.main(ThingsboardInstallApplication.java:43)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher.main(PropertiesLauncher.java:597)
Unexpected error during ThingsBoard installation!
```

Therefore, I tried fromVersion=2.4.3 as the installation instructions say. But that didn't work either:

```
thingsboard@thingsboard-1:~$ sudo /usr/share/thingsboard/bin/install/upgrade.sh --fromVersion=2.4.3
 ===================================================
 :: ThingsBoard ::       (v2.5.2)
 ===================================================

Starting ThingsBoard Upgrade from version 2.4.3 ...
Upgrading ThingsBoard from version 2.4.3 to 2.5.0 ...
Updating schema ...
Updating ts ...
Schema updated.
Updating schema ...
Updating attributes ...
Updating tenant...
Schema updated.
Upgrading ThingsBoard from version 2.5.0 to 2.5.1 ...
Unexpected error during ThingsBoard installation!
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to upgrade Cassandra database, unsupported fromVersion: 2.5.0
        at org.thingsboard.server.service.install.CassandraTsDatabaseUpgradeService.upgradeDatabase(CassandraTsDatabaseUpgradeService.java:52)
        at org.thingsboard.server.install.ThingsboardInstallService.performInstall(ThingsboardInstallService.java:146)
        at org.thingsboard.server.ThingsboardInstallApplication.main(ThingsboardInstallApplication.java:43)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher.main(PropertiesLauncher.java:597)
Unexpected error during ThingsBoard installation!
ThingsBoard upgrade failed
```

So which fromVersion should I use? Or am I doing something else wrong?

**Environment**

- OS:  Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
- ThingsBoard: 2.5.1 / 2.5.2
- Browser: Not applicable

See also https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/issues/3820

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to not run the upgrade script at all for this version.